How to open ComboBox dropdown with Down arrow key
In C# WPF application, I am using a ComboBox control with the IsEditable="True" property. When I press the Down arrow key on closed ComboBox, the next item in the ComboBox is selected without opening the dropdown. How to instead open the dropdown when the down arrow key is pressed, similar to how I can open it with Alt + Down arrow?
The reason I need the possibility to open dropdown using Down arrow key is that I want to optimize the ComboBox behavior for keyboard only and screen reader accessibility, and my screen reader does not provide any feedback about the currently selected item when changing item selection in ComboBox using the Down or Up arrow keys without opening the dropdown, but does provide feedback only after navigating within opened ComboBox dropdown when opened via Alt + Down arrow.
So far, I have the following code, which unfortunately does not work as the PreviewKeyDown event does not get fired if I press only the Down Arrow key without modifier. It gets fired for characters, Alt + down arrow etc. but not for down arrow.
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void MainWindow_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        commandComboBox.PreviewKeyDown += new KeyEventHandler(commandComboBox_PreviewKeyDown);
    }

    private void commandComboBox_PreviewKeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Key == Key.Down && !commandComboBox.IsDropDownOpen)
        {
            commandComboBox.IsDropDownOpen = true;
        }
    }

    }


Add a new class object to the Project (SHIFT+F2), name it ComboBoxEx (or whatever you prefer), then replace the class definition with this code, preserving the namespace, of course. Rebuild the Solution.
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Input;

[ToolboxItem(true)]
public class ComboBoxEx : ComboBox
{
    public ComboBoxEx() { }

    protected override void OnPreviewKeyDown(KeyEventArgs e) {
        int index = SelectedIndex;
        base.OnPreviewKeyDown(e);
        if (e.Key == Key.Down && !IsDropDownOpen) {
            IsDropDownOpen = true;
            SelectedIndex = index;
        }
    }
}

If you already have a ComboBox in the XAML, replace the instance name with local:ComboBoxEx (or whatever name you decided to assign to the class) and run the Project.
The SelectedIndex is stored before calling base.OnPreviewKeyDown(e), because the default behavior moves the selection to the next item in the list. This ensures that, when the drop-down is opened, the item selected is the one shown as the current text. Modify as required.

Thanks, got it working. For the ComboBoxEx in XAML, I also had to use x:Name="myComboBox" instead of Name="myComboBox"

Well, of course if you have to assign a Name to the Control (not mandatory), you have to prefix the Property with x:, since the object is defined in the same assembly (your application's)

I managed to do this in the PreviewKeyDown event like this:
private void ComboBox_PreviewKeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Key == Key.Down)
    {
        ((ComboBox)sender).IsDropDownOpen = true;
    }
}

This event handler listens for the Down key to be pressed and then opens the dropdown.
After testing, I see that this only works if IsEditable=False.

The Down arrow key event without modifier does not get fired. Other keys do. So this doesn't work for me.

It worked for me when the combo was focused using Tab. Are you sure you used PreviewKeyDown, because KeyDown really doesn't fire.

Yes, I am sure I am using PreviewKeyDown. I have modified the question to show the code I have so far, which does not work.

That is very strange, It clearly works for me. I am using .NET 8 on windows 11

From the source it seems that internal handling of PreviewKeyDown depends on the ComboBox being editable.

I will supplement EfraimNewman's answer.
You can change the behavior of an element using Behavior or Attached Property.
An example of implementing Attached Property:
    public class ComboBoxHelper
    {
        public static bool GetIsDropDownOpenDownArrow(ComboBox cBox)
        {
            return (bool)cBox.GetValue(IsDropDownOpenDownArrowProperty);
        }

        public static void SetIsDropDownOpenDownArrow(ComboBox cBox, bool value)
        {
            cBox.SetValue(IsDropDownOpenDownArrowProperty, value);
        }

        // Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for IsDropDownOpenDownArrow.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
        public static readonly DependencyProperty IsDropDownOpenDownArrowProperty =
            DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached(
                "IsDropDownOpenDownArrow",
                typeof(bool),
                typeof(ComboBoxHelper),
                new PropertyMetadata(false)
                {
                    PropertyChangedCallback = OnIsDropDownOpenDownArrowChanged
                });

        private static void OnIsDropDownOpenDownArrowChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            ComboBox cBox = (ComboBox)d;
            if (true.Equals(e.NewValue))
            {
                cBox.AddHandler(UIElement.PreviewKeyDownEvent, DownArrowHandler);
            }
            else
            {
                cBox.RemoveHandler(UIElement.PreviewKeyDownEvent, DownArrowHandler);
            }
        }

        private static readonly KeyEventHandler DownArrowHandler = (sender, e) =>
        {
            if (e.Key == Key.Down)
            {
                ComboBox cBox = (ComboBox)sender;
                if (!cBox.IsDropDownOpen)
                {
                    cBox.IsDropDownOpen = true;
                    e.Handled = true;
                }
            }
        };
    }

Example of use:
    public static class DataExample
    {
        public static ReadOnlyCollection<int> IntCollection { get; } =
            Array.AsReadOnly(Enumerable.Range(0, 10).Select(_ => Random.Shared.Next(100)).ToArray());
    }

    <UniformGrid Rows="1">
        <ComboBox ItemsSource="{x:Static local:DataExample.IntCollection}"
                  SelectedIndex="0" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
        <ComboBox ItemsSource="{x:Static local:DataExample.IntCollection}"
                  SelectedIndex="0" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                  local:ComboBoxHelper.IsDropDownOpenDownArrow="True"/>
    </UniformGrid>



Note from @EfraimNewman: this will only work or IsEditable=Fasle. The OP was asking for IsEditable=True

The corrected code OnIsDropDownOpenDownArrowChanged method and DownArrowHandler delegate takes this comment into account and adds the functionality of expanding the list also using the up arrow.
        private static void OnIsDropDownOpenDownArrowChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            ComboBox cBox = (ComboBox)d;
            if (true.Equals(e.NewValue))
            {
                cBox.AddHandler(UIElement.PreviewKeyDownEvent, DownArrowHandler, true);
            }
            else
            {
                cBox.RemoveHandler(UIElement.PreviewKeyDownEvent, DownArrowHandler);
            }
        }

        private static readonly KeyEventHandler DownArrowHandler = (sender, e) =>
        {
            if (e.Key is Key.Down or Key.Up)
            {
                ComboBox cBox = (ComboBox)sender;
                if (!cBox.IsDropDownOpen)
                {
                    cBox.IsDropDownOpen = true;
                    e.Handled = true;
                }
            }
        };



thanks, but the above code has no effect on the behavior of my ComboBox if I add to it the property local:ComboBoxHelper.IsDropDownOpenDownArrow="True"

@Adam
So there is something else that prevents the normal operation of the proposed Attached Property. The option that I showed you - on my computer works as expected. I attached a gif with a demonstration to my answer.

As i commented on my answer, this will only work or IsEditable=Fasle. The OP was asking for IsEditable=True so you need to use jimi's answer.

@EfraimNewman
Thank you! I did not pay attention to this nuance. I made corrections taking this remark into account.

Is there any reason why should I use your solution versus the one provided by Jimi, which is much more simpler?

@Adam
No.
Essentially, the difference between them is "programming guidelines." Some development teams have adopted one, others have adopted the other. Most teams do not recommend using Code Behind. Some corporate policies even prohibit its use. But the final choice is, of course, yours.
